# With Windows cmd or Cygwin, Is there a way to get the actually file path/name with proper case?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, cygwin

Is there a way, using Windows cmd or Cygwin, to get the actually file path/name with proper case? For example,

Input:

```
c:\windows\system32\display.dll
```

Output

```
C:\Windows\System32\Display.dll
```

Comment: `dir locationapi.dll`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `FOR /F` to echo or fetch the case corrected filename

```
for /F "delims=" %%X in ("c:\windows\system32\display.dll") do echo %%~fX
```

The case of the drive letter seems to be undetermined.
It can be upper or lower case for the same drive.
I tested it with

```
c:\> pushd C:\
C:\> popd
c:\> pushd c:\
c:\>
```

So you can simply force the drive letter to be always in lower case.

Comment: As addition `"delims="` to make use possible for paths/files with spaces?

Comment: Thanks. It works!
Although still with a lower "c:" drive letter, but that doesn't matter in my case, or at least much more easier to handle in scripting.

Comment: @RockWang I added more informations about the drive letter